# Why does putting Windows path into a variable does not replace a particular single slash with a double slash?

Tags: python, python-os

Why does the second slash does not get replaced with double slash when I do the following in Python shell?:

```
>>> p = 'M:\django\newenv\django_projects\mediaproject\mediaproject\media'
>>> p
'M:\\django\newenv\\django_projects\\mediaproject\\mediaproject\\media'
```

I think this is causing an error I am getting when trying to `os.listdir(p)`:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path
>   specified:
>   'M:\\django\newenv\\django_projects\\mediaproject\\mediaproject\\media'

Or is there any other cause of the error? The directory exists for sure and is copy-pasted from Windows file explorer.

**EDIT**:

I think this is because the second slash preceded the `n` character, so it gets treated as newline character. But how do I work around that (in real world I will not be typing the path manually)?

Comment: Probably becase `\n`, `\r` and `\t` are recognized as string terminators (newline, end of row and end of tab). To get around that, you manually escape your '\' character by adding another '\' infront of it. So you would have to define your path as `p = 'M:\\django\\newenv...'`. Suggest you use a module that is specifically designed to handle paths across OS-es. It's called [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Comment: if you use `r'your\path\goes\here'` python will read it as it is without special characters
so just an "r"

Comment: @BoboDarph: what if I will not be typing the path manually? The path will be read from Django's `MEDIA_ROOT` variable.

Comment: @barciewicz use os.path and os.environ to read env variables into paths. Something like this `test = os.path.abspath(os.environ['MEDIA_ROOT'])`. Do note that it will only work if MEDIA_ROOT is defined, so surround it in a try/catch to make sure you don't halt unexpectedly if that variable is missing from the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that `'\n'` is the control character NewLine, unicode U+0010. As neither `'\d'` nor `'\m'` are special they are left unchanged. It may be more clear when you try to print `p`:

```
>>> print(p)
M:\django
ewenv\django_projects\mediaproject\mediaproject\media
```

The `\` characters that appeared as `\\` are actually a single `\` in the string, and `\n` actually is a new line.

The 2 foolproof ways to insert `\` in a string are:

- consistently double them:

  ```
  p = 'M:\\django\\newenv\\django_projects\\mediaproject\\mediaproject\\media'
  ```
- use the `r'...'` construct:

  ```
  p = r'M:\django\newenv\django_projects\mediaproject\mediaproject\media'
  ```

The latter is easier when you copy/paste a path.

---

Beware, other `\x` characters are special: `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v`.
In addition, `'\xab'` is the character of code ab (for example '\x41' is 'A' in the ascii charset) `'\uabcd'` is the unicode character U+abcd, and `'\U00abcdef'` is the unicode character U+abcdef.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 p = r'M:\django\newenv\django_projects\mediaproject\mediaproject\media'

 os.listdir(p)
```

Adding a `r` before a string prevents escape sequence interpretation inside the string.  Therefore,  the string is only interpreted as a raw string.

The difference between a raw string and a normal string,  is how they deal with escape sequences.  A raw string will always treat a `\n` as two separate characters,  a `\` followed by a `n`. On the other hand a normal string will treat the `\n` as a single character.

**EX.**

```
raw_string = r"\n"
string = "\n"

print(len(raw_string)) 
print(len(string))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Working on the comments, I think OP needs a way to parse the `MEDIA_ROOT` env variable into an internal variable to his script.

To this goal, I suggest trying to get the environment variable using os.environ and parsing it into a python path with os.path.abspath.
Example code below:

```
import os
import os.path
try:
    media_root = os.path.abspath(os.environ['MEDIA_ROOT'])
except KeyError:
    media_root = None 
    # Alternatively you can just raise the exception here if you want to halt
```

Alternatively, if your MEDIA_ROOT variable comes directly from [django.conf.settings.MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/) you could, for your peace of mind, wrap it into an abspath, but I have a sneaky suspicion that django already does that for you.